# Object transformation using a functional approach

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a simple data set from a `data.txt` file. I would like to take this data and transform it into a specific object as per my example below. I have managed to get it into a somewhat usable JSON object but this is not ideal. I have included an example of the desired object.

Here is my `app.js` file:

```
let output = fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', 'UTF8')
.trim()
.split('\r\n')
.map((line) => line.split(';'))
.reduce((customers, line) => {
  customers.push({
    name: line[0],
    product: [{
      item: line[1],
      serial: line[2],
      year: line[3]
    }]
  })
  return customers
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2))
```

This currently the above NodeJs code returns the following array object:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Nancy",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "Macbook Pro",
        "serial": "A34D05980FCD4303",
        "year": "2019"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Nancy",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "iPad",
        "serial": "O0403X3028423C92",
        "year": "2015"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Nancy",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "iPhone",
        "serial": "X3830238S3309230",
        "year": "2017"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "Macbook Pro",
        "serial": "X2020J393983H380",
        "year": "2013"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "iPhone",
        "serial": "X38320093X032309",
        "year": "2015"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "fluffikins",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "iMac",
        "serial": "F392D392033X3232",
        "year": "2013"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "fluffikins",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "iPad",
        "serial": "FE322230D3223S21",
        "year": "2011"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is get the below object returned - ideally still following the same functional approach:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Nancy",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "Macbook Pro",
        "serial": "A34D05980FCD4303",
        "year": "2019"
      },
      {
        "item": "iPad",
        "serial": "O0403X3028423C92",
        "year": "2015"
      },
      {
        "item": "iPhone",
        "serial": "X3830238S3309230",
        "year": "2017"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "Macbook Pro",
        "serial": "X2020J393983H380",
        "year": "2013"
      },
      {
        "item": "iPhone",
        "serial": "X38320093X032309",
        "year": "2015"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "fluffikins",
    "product": [
      {
        "item": "iMac",
        "serial": "F392D392033X3232",
        "year": "2013"
      },
      {
        "item": "iPad",
        "serial": "FE322230D3223S21",
        "year": "2011"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my mock data set that lives in `data.txt`

```
Nancy;Macbook Pro;A34D05980FCD4303;2019
Nancy;iPad;O0403X3028423C92;2015
Nancy;iPhone;X3830238S3309230;2017
John;Macbook Pro;X2020J393983H380;2013
John;iPhone;X38320093X032309;2015
fluffikins;iMac;F392D392033X3232;2013
fluffikins;iPad;FE322230D3223S21;2011
```

Comment: Why does it have to be "functional"? Isn't "functioning" more important?

Comment: Also "product" doesn't really make sense for product*s*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an array you can use `Map` in reduce as accumulator, use `name` as key in Map and club value of all keys, finally just get the values `Map` to get desired output

```js
const data = `Nancy;Macbook Pro;A34D05980FCD4303;2019
Nancy;iPad;O0403X3028423C92;2015
Nancy;iPhone;X3830238S3309230;2017
John;Macbook Pro;X2020J393983H380;2013
John;iPhone;X38320093X032309;2015
fluffikins;iMac;F392D392033X3232;2013
fluffikins;iPad;FE322230D3223S21;2011`

const final = data.split('\n')
  .map(v => v.split(';'))
  .reduce((op, [name, item, serial, year]) => {
    let obj = { item, serial, year }
    if (op.has(name)) {
      op.get(name).products.push(obj)
    } else{
      op.set(name,{name, products:[obj]})
    }
  return op
}, new Map())
  
console.log([...final.values()])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "functional version" that utilizes a Map to find duplicates in O(1):

```
  (map => (
    fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', 'UTF8')
        .trim()
        .split('\r\n')
        .map((line) => line.split(';'))
        .forEach(([name, item, serial, year]) => 
           map.has(name)
             ? map.get(name).product.push({ item, serial, year })
             : map.set(name, { name, product: [{ item, serial, year }] })
         ),
    [...map.values()]
  )(new Map)
```

But seriously, whats so bad about imperative style?:

```
  const customers = new Map;
  const entries = fs.readFileSync('./data.txt', 'UTF8')
        .trim()
        .split('\r\n');

 for(const entry of entries) {
    const  [name, item, serial, year] = entry.split(";");
    const product = { item, serial, year };
    if(customers.has(name)) {
      customers.get(name).product.push(product);
    } else customers.set(name, { name, product: [product] });
 }

const result = [...customers.values()];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `.reduce` function to only add a new item to the array if there isn't one with that name. If there is, just add the product to that item's `product` array.

```js
const data = `Nancy;Macbook Pro;A34D05980FCD4303;2019
Nancy;iPad;O0403X3028423C92;2015
Nancy;iPhone;X3830238S3309230;2017
John;Macbook Pro;X2020J393983H380;2013
John;iPhone;X38320093X032309;2015
fluffikins;iMac;F392D392033X3232;2013
fluffikins;iPad;FE322230D3223S21;2011`;

const result = data.trim()
  .split('\n')
  .map((line) => line.split(';'))
  .reduce((customers, line) => {
    const product = {
      item: line[1],
      serial: line[2],
      year: line[3]
    };
    const customer = customers.find(({
      name
    }) => name === line[0]);
    if (customer) {
      customer.product.push(product);
    } else {
      customers.push({
        name: line[0],
        product: [product]
      });
    }
    return customers
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```